# How to set the result of time picker to TextField

Tags: android, android-timepicker, android-jetpack-compose

I want to set the result of time picker to TextField, how to achieve it by onValueChange?

```
@Composable
fun TestTimePickerTextField(
    selectTime: (Context) -> String
) {
    val context = ContextAmbient.current
    TextField(
        // How to pass result to TextField
    )
}

// viewModel
fun selectTime(context: Context): String {
    var time = ""
    val currentDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
    val startYear = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val startMonth = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val startDay = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    val startHour = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    val startMinute = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
    DatePickerDialog(context, { _, year, month, day ->
        TimePickerDialog(context, { _, hour, minute ->
            val pickedDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
            pickedDateTime.set(year, month, day, hour, minute)
            time = "$year-$month-$day $hour:$minute"
        }, startHour, startMinute, false).show()
    }, startYear, startMonth, startDay).show()
    return time
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewModel shouldn't contain methods with context. Put all android-related codeto activty/fragment.

In Activity:

```
@Composable
fun init() {
    val time by viewModel.time.observeAsState()
    MaterialTheme {
        Column {
            TextButton(onClick = { selectTime() }) {
                Text("Select time")
            }
            Text(time ?: "no time set")
        }
    }
}

private fun selectTime(): String {
    var time = ""
    val currentDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
    val startYear = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val startMonth = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val startDay = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    val startHour = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
    val startMinute = currentDateTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
    DatePickerDialog(this, { _, year, month, day ->
        TimePickerDialog(context, { _, hour, minute ->
            val pickedDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
            pickedDateTime.set(year, month, day, hour, minute)
            time = "$year-$month-$day $hour:$minute"
            viewModel.updateTime(time)
        }, startHour, startMinute, false).show()
    }, startYear, startMonth, startDay).show()
    return time
}
```

ViewModel class:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

var time = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun updateTime(time: String) {
    this.time.value = time
}
}
```